# How do I perfectly configure webpack to package the project of the main electron process?

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron

I know that packaging can be done by just configuring it like this:

```js
const CURRENT_DIT = process.cwd();

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    target: "electron-main",
    entry: CURRENT_DIT + "/src/main/main.js",
    output: {
        path: CURRENT_DIT + "/dist/main",
        filename: "main.js"
    }
}
```

But the generated main.js file integrates all the code, and even integrates all the dependencies' code together.

This directly brings the main.js size to 3MB and throws an exception:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at Object.t.exports (/tmp/.mount_eanyprzBaKKh/resources/app.asar/src/main/main.js:2:1399193)
    at a (/tmp/.mount_eanyprzBaKKh/resources/app.asar/src/main/main.js:2:1399413)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/.mount_eanyprzBaKKh/resources/app.asar/src/main/main.js:2:1399851)
    at Object.57006 (/tmp/.mount_eanyprzBaKKh/resources/app.asar/src/main/main.js:2:1399904)
    at __webpack_require__ (/tmp/.mount_eanyprzBaKKh/resources/app.asar/src/main/main.js:2:3041010)
    at Object.41847 (/tmp/.mount_eanyprzBaKKh/resources/app.asar/src/main/main.js:2:1348625)
    at __webpack_require__ (/tmp/.mount_eanyprzBaKKh/resources/app.asar/src/main/main.js:2:3041010)
    at Object.86669 (/tmp/.mount_eanyprzBaKKh/resources/app.asar/src/main/main.js:2:1350506)
    at __webpack_require__ (/tmp/.mount_eanyprzBaKKh/resources/app.asar/src/main/main.js:2:3041010)
    at Object.96052 (/tmp/.mount_eanyprzBaKKh/resources/app.asar/src/main/main.js:2:365620)
```

In fact, all I really need webpack to do is to remove all the comments, blank lines, and useless spaces in the code, and I don't need it to integrate all the code together.

Here is my source code directory structure:

```
src
└── main
    ├── config
    │   ├── index.js
    │   ├── IPCCommands.js
    │   └── preload.js
    ├── logger
    │   ├── ConsoleLogger.js
    │   ├── FileLogger.js
    │   └── index.js
    ├── main.js
    └── ProxyServerManager.js

3 directories, 8 files
```

I just want webpack to compile the code according to my original directory structure.

How should I do this?

webpack version: 5.68.0

webpack-cli version: 4.9.2

node version: v16.13.2

os: Linux

==========================================================

This is my config/index.js:

```js
const os = require("os")
const path = require("path");

const APPLICATION_NAME = "eanyproxy"

...

global.APPLICATION_NAME = APPLICATION_NAME
global.APPLICATION_DIR = APPLICATION_DIR
global.APPLICATION_LOGS_DIR = APPLICATION_LOGS_DIR
global.DEVELOPMENT = process.env.DEVELOPMENT && process.env.DEVELOPMENT === "true"
global.RENDER_BASE_URL = global.DEVELOPMENT ? "http://localhost:9000" : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../../dist/render")}`
```

This is my main.js:

```js
require("./config")
require("./logger")

const {app, BrowserWindow} = require("electron")
const path = require("path")
const psmanager = require("./ProxyServerManager")

const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, "../../dist/public/icon.png")

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    console.info("Render base url:", global.RENDER_BASE_URL)

    const loadWin = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 580,
        height: 200,
        frame: false,
        show: false,
        icon: iconPath,
        webPreferences: {contextIsolation: false, nodeIntegration: true}
    });
    loadWin.loadURL(`${global.RENDER_BASE_URL}/loading.html`).then(() => {
        loadWin.show()
    })

    const mainWin = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1300,
        height: 780,
        show: false,
        icon: iconPath,
        webPreferences: {
            devTools: global.DEVELOPMENT,
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, "./config/preload.js")
        }
    })

    mainWin.loadURL(`${RENDER_BASE_URL}/index.html`).then(() => {
        loadWin.close()
        mainWin.show()
        mainWin.webContents.openDevTools({activate: global.DEVELOPMENT, mode: "bottom"})
        psmanager.ipcListen()
    })
})
```

Comment: it seems that you have a problem inside your main.js can you share it?

Comment: @Novy I've added some critical code, is there a problem? They didn't have any problems when I developed them, it was only after I packaged as AppImage that this exception appeared.